# Cloudfront compression does not invalidate?

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I have been adjusting my AWS Cloudfront settings trying to optimize my site.

I tried turning compression on (a Y-Slow recommendation) and it corrupted the rendering of my site.

So I turned compression off, ran in invalidation on the whole directory tree, but the problem persists.  I have had to turn CDN off so my site will render.

Just for kicks I invalidated again, turned CDN on after waiting a bit, but still sending me compressed js and css files.

What did I miss?

Comment: Can you share a `dxxxexample.cloudfront.net/zzz` example URL of a file that seems to be working incorrectly?  Have you examined the `Date` and `Age:` and `X-Cache` headers of an object in question?  I always enable this option and have never seen unexpected behavior, so there's no "obvious" reason to expect problems.  When you invalidated "the whole directory tree," how did you do that?  Submit an invalidation request for `*`? Or something else?

Comment: Last first - submit and invalidation request for /*

Comment: If I request in isolation, it seems to work (send me non-compressed)  I changed a setting in Wordpress cache, and I can use CDN again.  Looking on my end...

Comment: Invalidating `*` or `/*` should be equivalent.  The [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html) actually say `/*` so what you did should be correct.

Answer (score -1):

How to upload a static HTML to S3 and use it as a Web Server

Pre­requisites:
­ You should have an IAM user with S3 access with the username and password 
ready

Some Caveats:

1. Minify the files yourselves [including CSS/JS and HTMLs] [There is no web server to do
   that]. 
   You can use grunt [preferably] or any online tool like http://www.willpeavy.com/minifier/
2. Gzip the files if you want to enable compression with the below

command: [Rememberto minify the files before you do this step]

­ gzip ­9  ­
 This will produce two files like file1.min.css.gz and file2.min.css.gz ­ Now remove the “.gz” extension with the help of mv command like: ­ mv file1.min.css.gz file1.min.css [similarly for file2.min.css.gz] ­

3. Sign­in into your AWS account and create a S3 bucket like mywebsite.com
   ○ Actions ­> Create Bucket
4. Right click on the S3 bucket and goto properties and click on enable website hosting.

Here you will have to enter the index document. This is the root file of your website. If it is located on the root and is named as index.html then simply write it as index.html

5. Go inside the bucket and click on Actions ­> Upload. On the popup, select your
   folder/drag and drop the files that you want.
6. Next ­ Click on Set Details [Tick mark the default selection and then click on Set
   Permissions]
7. Check mark on “Make Everything public” and click on Set Metadata
   Voila, you’re good to go!
8. Thereafter, click on Add metadata and add two things:

   Key:​ Cache­Control ​Value:​ max­age=2592000 [This number is in secs, modify this according to your needs] 
   Key:​ Content­Encoding ​Value:​ gzip
9. Now Click on Start Upload and at the end, you can access the site via the S3 link of the
   index page

Thanks : @karan-shah

Comment: This answer is a bit obsolete - CloudFront can now transparently serve compressed files without the developer needing to upload gziped files: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ServingCompressedFiles.html . That being said, I still have issues with invalidations not clearing compressed artifacts.